# Breakpoint filter by subclass?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, inheritance, breakpoints

Is it possible to set breakpoint so that it stop only if the given method is called from subclass?

I.e. both a method defined and breakpoint set are in superclass. Method is not overridden in subclass but is called for it. I need to catch only those cases, when it happen from given subclass.

This is suitable to track incorrect usage in highly branched libraries. For example class `VeryCoolAncestor` is called 1000 times, while only 1 of the calls are of my buggy class `B`.

I would like to know if it is possible in Eclipse. If it is not possible in Eclipse, then I would like to know any other debuggers where it is possible.

I need automation, so I don't need to know workarounds like inserting test calls in the code or test overriding methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional breakpoints in Eclipse.

Right click on the breakpoint, then select "Breakpoint Properties", then enable the "Conditional" checkbox and add an `instanceof` statement that satisfies your requirements:

[image]

Or, you can write a block just for debugging purposes, having one statement:

```
if(someCondition) {
    System.out.println("Breakpoint here");
}
```